# In header region: having 2 blocks on inlined

Tags: blocks, theming

In drupal7, I need to have 2 blocks in the header region, a search form and a menu.

By default, the theme "Skeleton 7" would stack up these 2 blocks.
How can I edit region--header.tpl.ph to have these 2 blocks on the same line?

Comment: Totally depends what theme you're using, how your regions are set up, your block/region templates, preprocessing, and plenty more. Without more information it's not going to be possible to help I'm afraid. In the simplest terms, search Google for "css float" or "css inline-block"

Comment: Sorry for that, complete beginner in Drupal question. I've just edited the question.